# Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог выбрать несколько дат мышкой CalendarWidget в PyQt5 и они отметились другим светом или рамкой

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qcalendarwidget

Я пытаюсь сделать приложение, где человек может выбрать несколько дат в календаре с помощи мышки и отметить в нем несколько дат и чтобы эти даты отметились другим шрифтом (цветом) или как-нибудь выделились например рамкой. Пример выделанных дат прилагаю в фото.

[image: Что должно получится при помощи выделения дат с помощью мыши]

Я нашел в гугле такое решение. Наследовал класс `QCalendarWidget` и переопределил метод `paintCell`, но не смог его сделать динамическим,  т.е. он уже создается в приложении только с отмеченными датами, не смог в него передать даты при клике, чтобы они отмечались.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QPoint, Qt


class Scheduler(QCalendarWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.events = {
        QDate(2021, 8, 5): ["Bob's birthday"],
        QDate(2021, 8, 16): ["Alice's birthday"]
    }

def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
    super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
    if date in self.events:
        painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
        painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QCalendarWidget::**clicked**(const QDate &date)
>
> Этот сигнал излучается при нажатии кнопки мыши. Дата щелчка мыши указывается по дате. Сигнал излучается только при нажатии на действительную дату, например, даты не выходят за пределы minimumDate() и maximumDate(). Если выбран режим NoSelection, этот сигнал не будет выдан.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QPoint, Qt


class Scheduler(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.events = {
            QDate(2021, 8, 5): ["Bob's birthday"],
            QDate(2021, 8, 16): ["Alice's birthday"]
        }
        
        self.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.show_date_func)

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date in self.events:
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3) 

    def show_date_func(self, date):  
        self.events[date] = 'Hello World'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Scheduler()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь, первый день регистрации и в первый же день когда задал вопрос, мне дали очень правильный и хороший ответ. Я над этим вопросом мучался 1 месяц, сдался и спросил, теперь мне стало многое понятно. Еще раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: @catharsis пожалуйста. Вам будет полезно также почитать  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+QCalendarWidget